# Загрузка страницы

Tags: php, javascript

При формировании данных на странице, до окончательной ее загрузке необходимо отобразить соответствующее сообщение, при окончании загрузки данных(полной прогрузке страницы) сообщение должно исчезнуть. Каким образом, желательно с примером, это можно реализовать.

Comment: Я так понимаю вам нужны прелоадеры/loader, в гугле полно примеров на эту тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться этой статьей, что бы получить представление как решить свою задачу - https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded